# Compare numbers: $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{2},\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^\frac{1}{e},\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to compare the following three numbers:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{2},\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^\frac{1}{e},\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{4}$$

The answers are easy to find but I am wondering what would be the best way to approach this. By the way, for comparing pairs in form $a^b,b^a$, I understand that we can take $\ln$ and study the function $f = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$

Using the similar method, we have

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{2} > \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^\frac{1}{e} \text{  if and only if  } \frac{\ln 2}{2}<\frac{\ln e}{e}, \text{  which is indeed the case.}$$

But what should I do to $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Well, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{4}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{3}} = \frac{1}{3}^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^\frac{1}{2}$ vs $\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{4}$, raise them both to the power of $8$.

Since they are both positive, their order will be preserved and you will get:

$$\left({\dfrac{1}{2}}\right)^4=\frac{1}{16}<\frac{1}{9}=\left({\dfrac{1}{3}}\right)^2$$

Comment: +1, with a nit: Surely raising to power 4 suffices?

Comment: @Macavity: Thanks. For these two values - I believe so. Is there anything that makes you suspect otherwise?